# LINQ to Entities - refreshing context

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have view in my database with i map to corensponding entity.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[OrdersTest]
AS
SELECT 
    CAST(1 as int) AS Id,
    'ORD-1' as DocumentNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CAST(2 as int) AS Id,
    'ORD-2' as DocumentNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CAST(3 as int) AS Id,
    'ORD-3' as DocumentNumber
```

Here is the code for load data

```cs
Context Con = new Context();
var expression = from orders in this.Con.OrdersTest select orders
ObservableCollection<OrdersTest> = ToObservableCollection<OrdersTest>(expression);
```

For the first time data is loaded correctly.
I want to simulate a change in my view. I edit view and changing value of DocumentNumber (application is still running).
Then i calling same code above, but data is not updating.

Is there any way to force refreshing data?

Comment: Why not create a new instance of your `DbContext` derived type? (EF follows the "unit of work" pattern, with an instance of `DbContext` representing the unit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AsNotracking` method which returns a new query where the entities returned will not be cached in the DbContext.

```
Context Con = new Context();
var expression = from orders in this.Con.OrdersTest.AsNoTracking() select orders
ObservableCollection<OrdersTest> = ToObservableCollection<OrdersTest>(expression);
```